# In circular motion is acceleration vector and $\frac{dv}{dt}$ the same?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, differentiation, speed

I was studying a book in which they have written this

$$ a = -w^{2} r \hat{e} + \frac{dv
}{dt} \ddot{e} \tag{1} \label{1}$$

Where $a$ is acceleration vector $\hat{e}$ is unit radial vector and $\ddot{e}$ is unit tangential vector.

My question is $a$ vector and $\frac{dv}{dt}$ the same?

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is a simple number (no direction associated), then no, $\text{d}v/\text{d}t$ is not necessarily equal to $a$.  In circular motion, it is often the case that $\text{d}{v}/\text{d}t=0$, but $a$ is not zero.

If $\vec{v}$ is a vector, then $\text{d}\vec{v}/\text{d}t$ is indeed $\vec{a}$.

Your book has decomposed acceleration (which is a vector) into its component directions.